# Xamarin Create Binding project for StripeTerminal

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I am attempting to create a binding project for the StripeTerminal CocoaPod ([Stripe Terminal iOS](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-ios)). I setup the pod file. Then using the Xamarin docs, I installed Objective Sharpie, and used

`sharpie pod bind`

which created two files. StripeTerminal_ApiDefinitions.cs and StripeTerminal_StructsAndEnums.cs. Those files look good and have the methods I am expecting when I was using a XCode project.

I then pointed added a Native Reference to the StripeTerminal framework file, but it seems a link file was not created. The Xamarin help documentions mention that a iOS Native Library ends in .a, while this framework does not. I tried pointing the native reference to the folder of the framework, to the extensionless library, and even renamed the library project to .a. Each time when I attempt to build it gives me an error of "No API definition file specified".

Comment: Yes, both files were added then I added the Native Reference. Next build it gave the No API definition file specified error.

Comment: Looks like they are on Compile at the moment. What should the two .cs files be set to for their build action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API definition file(s) should have a build action of `ObjcBindingApiDefinition`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ObjcBindingApiDefinition Include="ApiDefinition.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And your Enum|Structs file(s) should have a build action of `ObjcBindingCoreSource`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ObjcBindingCoreSource Include="Structs.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```